# Where can I find United 757 Checklists? (CRM, Pre Start, Pre Takeoff)

Tags: boeing, commercial-operations, boeing-757

Where can I find United 757 Checklists (CRM, Pre-Start, Pre-Takeoff)? I need these for a writing project that I am doing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Thanks, Charlie :)

Comment: If you need those specific and current checklists your best bet is to ask them directly with a heartwarming story and hope - but given that they cost a lot of money to make I don’t like your chances. You might be able to find ones created for flight simming which might not be 100% accurate but close enough.

Comment: Make friends with a United pilot flying 757s?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you can get an airline specific checklist for an airplane, but for Boeing 757-200, a generic one is available. Please note that they might be for simulators (as [Ben mentioned](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45689/where-can-i-find-united-757-checklists-crm-pre-start-pre-takeoff#comment118083_45689)) but are close enough.

- [PDF](https://www.atlanticsunairways.com/training/checklist_b757.pdf)
- [Trello](https://trello.com/b/1j4IYSUm/boeing-757-checklist)
- [X-Plane](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/files/file/35729-757-200-pw-checklistpdf/) (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Did you find these in X-Plane 11? Where did you get them?